# The probability of detecting a defect given defect growth when the two variables are independent

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I am dealing with a real world problem and just wanted to check if I am going about this the right way. I have the probabilities that

- a defect will grow within a particular structure, say ${\rm P}(X_1)$
- a person will be able to detect a defect, say ${\rm P}(X_2)$.

These are two completely independent variables.

I am trying to determine the probability that a defect will be detected given that there is defect growth in the structure. Can I just multiply the two?

Comment: Which two variables are independent you say ?

Comment: @Karl Oskar The probability that there is _defect growth_ and the probability that _the defect is detected_.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ denote the event that a defect exists/grows, and this has probability $P(A) = P(X_1)$ in your notation. Let $B$ denote the event that the expert 
tester *announces* there there is a defect, that is, *claims* to have detected a defect, whether or not a defect actually exists. Your $P(X_2)$, the probability that the tester will be able to *detect* a defect is actually $P(B\mid A)$, and it is exactly what you are claiming that you want to find when you say *the probability that a defect will be detected given that there is defect growth in the structure.*  No need to multiply which would give you $P(B\mid A)P(A) = P(A\cap B)$, the probability that a defect is announced **and** there is a defect. This is a probability of some interest but not the probability
that you say you want to find.

A more interesting probability would be $P(A\mid B)$, the probability that
a defect actually exists *given* that your expert tester has claimed that
a defect exists, and this is where Bayes' formula is needed since you
want to "turn the conditioning around" and deduce $P(A\mid B)$ from knowledge
of $P(B \mid A)$. Bayes' formula says that
$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}
= \frac{P(B \mid A)P(A)}{P(B \mid A)P(A) + P(B\mid A^c)P(A^c)}.$$
You don't provide enough information for this formula to be used; you
know $P(B\mid A), P(A)$ and $P(A^c) = 1-P(A)$ but you also
need $P(B\mid A^c)$, the probability that the expert tester (mistakenly)
claims that a defect exists when in fact there is no defect. As they
say, it is not what you don't know that will kill you; it is what you
know that just a'in't so.

Comment: +1. Good to see an answer that clearly shows why one has to take care, and in particular be explicit, when defining events and their probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I am confused with the wording. Do you want the probability that a defect will be detected, given that a defect is there. That is just $P(X2)$ i.e by Bayes rule.

$$
P(X2|X1) = \frac{P(X1) P(X2)}{P(X1)} = P(X2)
$$

If you want the joint probability that there is a defect AND it is detected, then you can multiply these two assuming independence.

Comment: I am looking at the probability that there is _defect growth_ AND that a _defect is detected_. I guess I should just multiply then.

Comment: Yes, if you are looking for the joint probability $P(X1, X2)$, then assuming that they are independent, you have $P(X1, X2) = P(X1) P(X2)$

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to be sure I was doing the right thing.

Comment: You made a typo on Bayes rule. It should be $P(X_1|X_2)P(X_2)$ on the numerator.

Comment: $P(X1|X2) = P(X1)$ because $X1$ and $X2$ are independent

Comment: ok, but that's what you're trying to show. If you have $P(X_1|X_2)=P(X_1)$ to start off with then you already have $P(X_2|X_1)=P(X_2)$ by switching the roles of $X_1$ and $X_2$ so why use Bayes rule at all?

Comment: It was just an illustration of why it is $P(X2|X1) = P(X2)$, which was one of the things the OP was confused about.

Comment: are you sure that this argument holds? You're trying to show P(X2|X1)=P(X2) but you've used that fact in the guise P(X1|X2)=P(X1) in your reasoning. Bayes rule itself is derived from the conditional probability formula $P(A|B)=P(AB)/P(B) \implies P(AB)=P(A|B)P(B)$ (together with the formula for $P(B|A)$) and you would be better off looking at the conditional probability formula directly in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, I should have probably made it slightly clear that the numerator joint probability $P(X1, X2) = P(X1) P(X2)$ assuming independence.

Answer (score 1):

By definition the joint probability $P(X_1,X_2)$ factorizes into $P(X_1)P(X_2)$ when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. So, given independence, $P(X_1,X_2)=P(X_1)P(X_2)$.

> I am trying to determine the probability that a defect will be detected given that there is defect growth in the structure.

By definition the conditional probability
$$ P(X_2|X_1) = \frac{P(X_2,X_1)}{P(X_1)} = \frac{P(X_2)P(X_1)}{P(X_1)} = P(X_2) $$

where independence has been used to factorize $P(X_2,X_1)$. Similarly, $P(X_1|X_2)=P(X_1)$ when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.